Lock wait timeout exceeded with an embedded Quartz scheduler
Good day all.
We have a somewhat old Spring microservice application that uses Quartz scheduler. Quartz is not running standalone and imbedded in one of the services. Recently we did a load test of the application and after certain load we'd get this error Wrapped by: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, restarting MySQL solved the issue but currently we're trying to work on the fix but not sure if it's on MySQL side or Quartz side.
Regarding the Quartz scheduler there is no custom configuration and the only thing is this defined in application.properties: spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc.
So far I've tried adding these two lines to application.properties:
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.acquireRetryCount=7 spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.acquireRetryDelay=2000
but with that the application fails to boot with the error:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No setter for property 'acquireRetryCount' [52 skipped] ... 50 common frames omitted Wrapped by: org.quartz.SchedulerException: JobStore class 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' props could not be configured. ...
Not having a configuration for quartz makes it all confusing and I'm not sure how to apply the answers from similar posts because they do have a custom quartz configuration, so any hints and help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Where did you get those properties? As those are on no list of supported quartz properties. Which version of Spring Boot and Quartz are you using.

@M.Deinum I probably chatGPT'ed it :) do not recall exactly atp. I believe Quartz is 2.3.2, and Spring boot is 2.7.9

Can you please show all the properties that has been set for the spring.quarts.* section? Have you set the isClustered flag (if you are using the scheduler on multiple instances of the service, with one db that is used by every one, like in https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html)?

@FrancescoPoli interestingly the only property set regarding quartz is   spring.quartz.job-store-type: jdbc, thus I think no, no isClustered flag is set either

I suggest you to add spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true to your properties and check if this solves the locking issue.

We have only one service that uses Quartz scheduler so I do not think this architecture is what we have but I of course could try @FrancescoPoli

Is the service that embeds Quartz replicated? It's not just different kind of services, but also the number of running instances. If you have more than one instance that is running at the same time, you have to manage this as a "cluster".

@FrancescoPoli no, it's not replicated :) Only one instance of the service with Quartz is running
